# How to efficiently Append a result of an operation on each element of a list to itself?

Tags: programming, list-manipulation

I'm looking for the best function to apply the product of the last two elements of sublist elements to each element:

#### Example:

```
(*Input:*)
 {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, ...}  

(*Desired output:*)
```

> ```
> {{x1, y1, z1, y1 z1}, {x2, y2, z2, y2 z2}, ...}
> ```

I know I could just use a `Do` loop with an index `k` and do it element by element with `AppendTo`, but I guess there is a faster method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My proposition:

```
list = RandomReal[1., {100000, 3}];

newlist = Transpose[{Sequence @@ Transpose[list],
    list[[All, 2]] list[[All, 3]]}];
```

A little benchmark using other answers:

```
In[51]:= list = RandomReal[1., {1000000, 3}];

In[52]:= newlist = 
   Transpose[{Sequence @@ Transpose[list], 
     list[[All, 2]] list[[All, 3]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[52]= {0.056405, Null}

In[53]:= newlist2 = {##, Times[##2]} & @@@ list; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[53]= {0.970229, Null}

In[54]:= newlist3 = 
   Append[#, #[[2]] #[[3]]] & /@ list; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[54]= {0.454465, Null}

In[55]:= insertHereThis[list_List, here_Integer, this_] := 
 Insert[#, this[#], here] & /@ list

In[56]:= newlist4 = 
   insertHereThis[list, 2, #[[2]] #[[3]] &]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[56]= {0.438192, Null}

In[57]:= func = Join[#, Partition[#[[All, -1]] #[[All, -2]], 1], 2] &;

In[58]:= newlist5 = func[list]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[58]= {0.053084, Null}

In[60]:= newlist6 = 
   ArrayFlatten[{{#, Transpose[{times[#, 2, 3]}]}}] &[
    list]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[60]= {0.022477, Null}
```

EDIT: Added new answer (Mr.Wizard's), which now is the fastest in my machine.

EDIT2: Added Leonid's compiled version, and he is right, it is twice faster!

Answer (score 10):

You could use `Apply` for this, e.g.

```
list = Transpose[{Range[10], RandomInteger[10, 10], RandomReal[1, 10]}];

{##, Times[##2]} & @@@ list
```

Comment: Note that `Apply` does not in general benefit from auto-compilation, in contrast to `Map` (I mention this since efficiency was mentioned in the question's title).

Answer (score 8):

I propose:

```
func = Join[#, Partition[#[[All, -1]] #[[All, -2]], 1], 2] &;

func @ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 30}, {7, 8, 9, 72}}
> ```

Comment: I edited my answer to include yours in my benchmarks, now yours is the winner :).

Answer (score 7):

Can use `ReplaceAll`:

```
   list = {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}};
   list /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, y, z, y z}
```

Or `Insert`:

```
   ins=Insert[#, #[[2]] #[[3]], -1]&;
   ins/@list
```

Both give

> ```
>  {{a, b, c, b c}, {e, f, g, f g}}
> ```

For inserting a function of the data in a row  in a column of your choice, define

```
  insertHereThis[list_List, here_Integer, this_] := 
   Insert[#, this[#], here] & /@ list
```

and use it as:

```
  insertHereThis[list, 2, #[[[2]]#[[3]]&]
```

to get

> ```
> {{a, b c, b, c}, {e, f g, f, g}}
> ```

or as

```
  insertHereThis[list, 3, 5 &]
```

to get

> ```
> {{a, b, 5, c}, {e, f, 5, g}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for the ultimate speed, you can use a custom compiled multiplication function, such as

```
times  = 
  Compile[{{lst, _Real, 2}, {indi, _Integer}, {indj, _Integer}},
     Module[{res = Table[0., {Length[lst]}]},
       Do[res[[i]] = 
           Compile`GetElement[lst, i, indi]*
           Compile`GetElement[lst, i, indj], 
         {i, Length[lst]}
       ];
       res],
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Then,

```
ArrayFlatten[{{#, Transpose[{times[#, 2, 3]}]}}] &[list]
```

will do the job. My benchmarks on large lists show that this is about twice faster than the much more elegant version of @Mr.Wizard, which is the fastest of the already posted solutions. The reason it is faster is that I save on one column extraction (such as `list[[All,2]]`), which is a costly operation, by doing multiplication in-place.

Comment: Leonid, how does this compare to Rojo's method on your system?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Mine is still about 1.5 - 2x faster. The idea on double-`Transpose` did cross my mind, but I somehow dismissed it without even trying. Mat be that was a mistake.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my innocent but quite efficient

```
mifunc = Transpose[Append[#, #[[-1]] #[[-2]]]&[Transpose[#]]] &;
```

Which can also be written:

```
Append[#, #[[-1]] #[[-2]]] &[#\[Transpose]]\[Transpose] &
```

Which appears in a Notebook as:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, that's a lot faster than I expected.  Nicely done!

Answer (score 6):

For example

```
list = RandomInteger[100, {15, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{93, 38, 76}, {72, 28, 8}, {4, 51, 96}, {52, 28, 26},
>    {37, 73, 93}, {33, 32, 61}, {11, 64, 96}, {28, 97, 11}, 
>    {74, 76, 0}, {83, 4,  9}, {31, 85, 15}, {38, 34, 27}, 
>    {42, 54, 75}, {47, 45, 78}, {87, 27, 94}}
> ```

```
Append[#, #[[2]] #[[3]]] & /@ list
```

> ```
> {{93, 38, 76, 2888}, {72, 28, 8, 224}, {4, 51, 96, 4896}, 
>    {52, 28, 26, 728}, {37, 73, 93, 6789}, {33, 32, 61, 1952}, 
>    {11, 64, 96, 6144}, {28, 97, 11, 1067}, {74, 76, 0, 0}, 
>    {83, 4, 9, 36}, {31, 85, 15, 1275}, {38, 34, 27, 918}, 
>    {42, 54, 75, 4050}, {47, 45, 78, 3510}, {87, 27, 94, 2538}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}};
```

`Splice` came with V 12.1

```
{Splice @ #, Splice @ Rest @ #} & /@ list
```

{{a, b, c, b, c}, {e, f, g, f, g}}

Or slot-free with `Query`

```
Query[All, {Splice, Splice @* Rest}] @ list
```

{{a, b, c, b, c}, {e, f, g, f, g}}

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same as Rojo's idea, but it appears to be 10% faster on my system (M1 Max):

```
result = Block[{x, y, z},
   {x, y, z} = Transpose[list];
   Transpose[{x, y, z, y z}]
   ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst={{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2},{x3,y3,z3}}

MapThread[Append,{#,#[[All,2]] #[[All,3]]}]&@lst

(*{{x1,y1,z1,y1 z1},{x2,y2,z2,y2 z2},{x3,y3,z3,y3 z3}} *)
```

Somewhat simpler:

```
MapThread[Append[#,#[[2]] #[[3]] ]&,{lst}]

(* {{x1,y1,z1,y1 z1},{x2,y2,z2,y2 z2},{x3,y3,z3,y3 z3}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cases`:

```
lst = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};

Cases[lst, x_ :> {Sequence @@ x, Times @@ Rest[x]}]

(*{{x1, y1, z1, y1 z1}, {x2, y2, z2, y2 z2}, {x3, y3, z3, y3 z3}}*)
```

Or using **Internal`PartitionRagged**:

```
{Sequence @@ #, Times @@ Last@Internal`PartitionRagged[#, {1, 2}]} & /@ lst

(*{{x1, y1, z1, y1 z1}, {x2, y2, z2, y2 z2}, {x3, y3, z3, y3 z3}}*)
```