# Partition sublists of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have the following list:

```
l1={{2015, 5, 6, 13692}, {2015, 5, 7, 13715}, {2015, 5, 10,  13274}, 
  {2015, 5, 11, 13581}, {2015, 5, 12, 13609}};
```

How is it possible to rearrange so it becomes

```
l2={{{2015, 5, 6}, 13692}, {{2015, 5, 7}, 13715}, {{2015, 5, 10},  13274},
 {{2015, 5, 11}, 13581}, {{2015, 5, 12}, 13609}}
```

That is, I want to partition each sublist of l1 and make it look like l2.

Comment: `Composition[Through, {Most, Last}] /@ l1`?

Comment: Thanks!!! It works.

Comment: related: [2688](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2688/5478)

Comment: Argument destructuring works well in this situation. After defining `restructure[{a__, b_}] := {{a}, b}`, `restructure /@ l1` gives the desired result.

Answer (score 8):

```
l1 = {{2015, 5, 6, 13692}, {2015, 5, 7, 13715}, {2015, 5, 10, 13274}, {2015, 5, 11, 13581}, {2015, 5, 12, 13609}}

l1 /. {a__, b_?AtomQ} :> {{a}, b}
```

or

```
Replace[l1, {a__, b_} :> {{a}, b}, {1}]
```

> {{{2015, 5, 6}, 13692}, {{2015, 5, 7}, 13715}, {{2015, 5, 10}, 13274},    {{2015, 5, 11}, 13581}, {{2015, 5, 12}, 13609}}

Another possibility with `Part`

```
{#[[1 ;; 3]], #[[4]]} & /@ l1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both work. The second answer with 'Replace' is fantastic. I understand it since it's more close to my level!

Answer (score 5):

and a classic:

```
{{#, #2, #3}, #4} & @@@ l1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 // {#[[All, ;; 3]], #[[All, -1]]} & // Transpose
```

> {{{2015, 5, 6}, 13692}, {{2015, 5, 7}, 13715}, {{2015, 5, 10}, 
>     13274}, {{2015, 5, 11}, 13581}, {{2015, 5, 12}, 13609}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = 
 {{2015, 5, 6, 13692}, {2015, 5, 7, 13715}, {2015, 5, 10, 13274}, 
  {2015, 5, 11, 13581}, {2015, 5, 12, 13609}};
```

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0)

```
Comap[{Most, Last}] /@ list
```

{{{2015, 5, 6}, 13692}, {{2015, 5, 7}, 13715}, {{2015, 5, 10},
13274}, {{2015, 5, 11}, 13581}, {{2015, 5, 12}, 13609}}

Using `Query`

```
Query[All, {Most, Last}] @ list
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{2015, 5, 6, 13692}, {2015, 5, 7, 13715}, 
        {2015, 5, 10, 13274}, {2015, 5, 11, 13581},
        {2015, 5, 12, 13609}};
```

---

Using `SlotSequence` and `MapApply`:

```
Through[{Most, Last}@{##}] & @@@ list

(*{{{2015, 5, 6}, 13692}, {{2015, 5, 7}, 13715},
 {{2015, 5, 10}, 13274}, {{2015, 5, 11}, 13581}, 
 {{2015, 5, 12}, 13609}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {{2015, 5, 6, 13692}, {2015, 5, 7, 13715}, {2015, 5, 10, 
    13274}, {2015, 5, 11, 13581}, {2015, 5, 12, 13609}};

FlattenAt[#, -1] &@Partition[#, UpTo[3]] & /@ l1
FlattenAt[#, -1] &@TakeList[#, {3, 1}] & /@ l1  
FlattenAt[#, -1] &@TakeDrop[#, 3] & /@ l1
{Take[#, 3], Last@#} & /@ l1
SequenceCases[#, {a__, b_} :> Sequence @@ {{a}, b}] & /@ l1
```

---

*Result:*

> {{{2015, 5, 6}, 13692}, {{2015, 5, 7}, 13715}, {{2015, 5, 10},
> 13274}, {{2015, 5, 11}, 13581}, {{2015, 5, 12}, 13609}}

Answer (score 2):

```
b = Map[List[Flatten@Partition[#, 3], Last[#]] &, l1]
```