# Plot of a data list evaluated with other function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I want to evaluate a function of "two" variables using some data points (x,y(x)) (but one of them is related to the other) that I have made with the function `Table`.

My table of data (x,y(x)) that I have build in Mathematica using `Table` with a given complicated implicit equation is something like:

```
data = {{1.35, 3.56}, {1.55, 4.78}, {1.76, 8.89},...}
```

And imagine that I have the following function:

```
f[x_, y_] := x*y / (x^2 + y^2)
```

Now I want to evaluate my list of data points $(x,y(x))$ using my function, and make a plot of that, so plotting actually $f(x)$, because $y(x)$ is not an independent variable. How can that be done?

EXAMPLE:

If I evaluate the list `data` under the previous function, I will obtain something like

```
evaluation = {{1.35, 0.331}, {1.55, 0.293}, {1.76, 0.191}}
```

So precisely I want to do a plot of these points, but in a systematic way of course.

Comment: very closely related: [2688](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2688/5478). Is `ListPlot3D[ {##, f[##]}& @@@ data]` what you want?

Comment: okay, so I have eddited my post. Actually it's not a function f(x,y), it's given by y(x), so at the end the function is only for a given variable x, because the other is related like y(x) by the table of points

Comment: Then isn't `data` already the table of `{x,y}`? Use `ListLinePlot[data]`?

Comment: no, I have edited the post again for clarify

Comment: Generate the processed data using `{#1, f[#1, #2]} & @@@ data` then use `ListPlot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is define `f` a little different than the way you show.

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {x, x y/(x^2 + y^2)}
```

With this definition,

```
data = {{1.35, 3.56}, {1.55, 4.78}, {1.76, 8.89}};
f /@ data
```

gives

> `{{1.35, 0.331537}, {1.55, 0.293415}, {1.76, 0.190508}}`